# Is there a way to know if the Debian 'testing' repo is open or not in Debian

Tags: debian, apt

Couple of weeks back, Debian 11 was [released](https://www.debian.org/News/2021/20210814). Now I know it usually takes anywhere between 2-4 weeks for the testing repo. to be opened. Is there a way to know that? Some command or something.? The only way I know is just to have the path in /etc/apt/sources.list and then either apt update or apt-get update and see if it works or not, if it doesn't, it doesn't. But that seems like a trial and error thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The testing repositories don’t disappear during a release; what changes is that package propagation from unstable to testing is disabled. Users of testing don’t need to change anything in their local configuration, or watch for any particular event.

For developers, changes are announced on [the `debian-devel-announce` list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/); [the start of the Bookworm development cycle](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2021/08/msg00001.html) was announced there on August 15. As far as I’m aware, there was no email announcement when propagation was re-enabled, but that happened on August 16 — my packages which were waiting in unstable [migrated then](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1246871/sdl12-compat-00git20210628cf47f88-1-migrated-to-testing/).

So updates have been flowing into testing since August 16, two days after the release of Debian 11.